# Adding Ninject.MVC3 to existing MVC(4) project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am working on a project with MVC4, and have decided that I wish to add some dependency injection via Ninject.  After download/install via NuGet, I find this error in the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` (Line 23):

```
The type 'System.Web.IHttpModule' is defined in an assembly 
that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 
'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

and then a bit later (line 44):

```
The type or namespace name 'IHttpModule' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I expect that this Normally works, but that I've done something that doesn't work when adding Ninject to the project after the fact.

Edit:  The above errors are only thrown by the test project....

Comment: I am not aware of any way in which it is not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure you specify the System.Web reference in both the main and test project. The test projects have their own list of references to maintain. I expect you don't have System.Web in the test project.

Comment: Ugh...that was it...so simple **facepalm**

Comment: I don't understand why the reference in the test project affects the NinjectWebCommon.cs file when it's in a different project within the solution... I had the reference within my 'Models' and 'MVC' projects within my solution.  Adding the reference to the test project did work though :)

Comment: Yep, I opened up my Project.Test and went to add reference > Assemblies > System.Web. Checked it, added it and no more errors!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Ninject didn't add web references to your model project.